# Side Effects Implementation in SAP Fiori Elements

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a managed Restful ABAP Application with a worklist items and header info for summary on the object view page.
Whenever I change a value in the worklist item field through an action (e.g set_status button), I want my header information is updated as well accordingly.

I've seen documentations on the [official site](https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/1809.000/en-US/18b17bdd49d1436fa9172cbb01e26544.html), how you can do that with side effects defined in the annotations.xml but it just doesnt work for me.

Is there a way to debug this somehow? Or have you managed to make it work? If so can you please copy your solution here?

Thank in advance.
CP

Comment: Why would this be an action? I guess your header should have a field status, which is updated.

Comment: Hi @BenediktKromer. The header is indeed a groupField item, however the record which gets updated is coming from a worklist item. The update happens on a button(action) click, however the header UI Object does not gets updated immediately. Either a refresh (new odata call) will reflect the changes on the header. Or I have to implement things called "Side Effects". Based on the documentation, it is just a "setting" in the annotation model. However it just doesnt work for me. If you have a working solution, it would be highly appreciate if you could share it here.

Comment: You need to be more clear. "Not updated" means it's updated but the UI has no refresh? Ist this Fiori Elements or native? How is the update triggered? V2 or V4. How dose the data model looks like?